# How to execute two time, same JQuery function with different args

Tags: jquery

I am integrating on my site a code which calls in Jquery something located on the site of the service which proposes this solution.

I'm trying to get rates from companies via this solution. In their documentation, it is possible to filter which company to display. This code allows via the argument tag= to filter (for example tag=sbb).

In my final goal, I wanted to put several times this code on the page, once for "sbb", once for "bls", once for "ra" in order to have the 3 companies in order. Otherwise, if I leave the tag empty, all the results are displayed mixed up.

Problem, if I put 3x this code on the page, I have the impression that the service does not know which request to answer and it answers me 3x the same thing. But if I run the whole thing 1x, it gives me the right results that are requested via the "tag=" argument.

Do you have an idea?

The part of the code

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var args = {'app_url':'url to the app','price':'CHF', 'tag':'sbb'};
getprice(args);
});
```

Comment: Put the tags in an array and loop through it, providing the specific tag to the `getprice()` function argument.

Comment: Depends on how you form your `args`. If you make it an array, just iterate it. `for (let arg of args) { getprice(arg); }` maybe? Edit: Ah, Rory beat me to it.